# C# Process: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, process, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003-r2

Please excuse me if I am asking a dumb question as I am a novice programmer on C#.

I am seeing different behavior of Process on Windows Server 2008 and 2003.

Below is my code snippet:

```
            Process job = new Process();
            job.StartInfo.FileName = global.m_sShell;
            job.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            job.StartInfo.Arguments = EXE;
            job.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            job.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            job.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            job.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            shellScriptRetCode = job.Start();
```

"global.m_sShell" is a string that contains a system path like "E:\abc\ksh.exe".
[This string has been fetched from a registry key]

The process starts well on Windows Server 2008 but on Windows Server 2003 (32-bit) I am getting error

```
             The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have checked the file manually and it exists on the server.
Now, if I hard code the filename like:

```
            job.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\abc\ksh.exe";
```

it works fine.

The thing is that I have to fetch the path key from registry and use that to launch the process.

Please provide me with your expert comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the content of the registry key? For example it could contain some unprintable characters

Comment: debug the string (by printing to the console or by adding break point in code) you fetch from the registry and see if its a valid one.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your input! 
Actually on server 2008 the path key is: "E:\abc\ksh" and on server 2003 it is "E:\abc\ksh.exe -l". 
Thanks once again!